# Converting ArrayOfStrings to string array

Tags: c#, web-services

I have searched for a long time and tried different ways to solve this problem without any success.

My current program is as follows:

- **Web service:** DAL, Controller and WebService(with web methods)
- **Windows form:** Controller(receives the web service) and Form

I receive a string array in the DAL that I try to send through the web service to my `Controller` in the windows form program. But receive the error:

> Cannot implicity convert type
>   'WindowsFormApplication.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>'

**Controller in form:**

```
 public List<string[]> GetAllEmployee()
 {
     return client.GetAllEmployee();
 }
```

**Webservice:**

```
public List<string[]> GetAllEmployee()
{
    return cont.GetAllEmployee();
}
```

**DAL:**

```
 public List<string[]> GetAllEmployee()
 {
     GetConnection();
     con.Open();
     stmt = con.CreateCommand();
     stmt.CommandText = "SELECT [No_],[First Name],[Last Name],[Initials],[Job Title],[E-Mail] FROM [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee]";
     OdbcDataReader reader = stmt.ExecuteReader();

     List<string[]> allEmployee = new List<string[]>();

     String[] cols = new string[5];
     for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; ++i)
     {
         cols[i] = reader.GetName(i);
     }
     allEmployee.Add(cols);
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         string[] s = new string[cols.Length]; 
         for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) 
         {
             s[i] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); 
         }

         allEmployee.Add(s);
     }
     con.Close();
     return allEmployee;
 }
```

**Controller:**

```
public List<string[]> GetAllEmployee()
{
    return dal.GetAllEmployee();
}
```

**client:**

```
ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
```

Comment: can you provide full error message? and also definition for `client.GetAllEmployee();` and `cont.GetAllEmployee();` too

Comment: Certainly, "Cannot implicity convert type 'WindowsFormApplication.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>'. Client: ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient(); //and the controller (cont.GetAllEmployee)://
public List<string[]> GetAllEmployee()
        {
            return dal.GetAllEmployee();
        }

Comment: Edit/add it to your question.

Comment: Edited instead, sry!

Comment: Specifically where is your error occurring? First-pass spot-check on your code here doesn't seem to indicate any issues.

Comment: so, what return `client.GetAllEmployee();`?

Comment: @EBrown methinks `client.GetAllEmployee();` return _string[]_ but method try return _List<string[]>_

Comment: @Grundy That is my suspicion as well. Unless he has a custom type defined. Also, why don't you create an `Employee` object that you populate with **meaningful** names? I.e. `Employee.Number`, `Employee.FirstName`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your service returns the type `WindowsFormApplication.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfString` which needs to be explicitly converted to `List<string>` with [ToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method:

```
return dal.GetAllEmployee().ToList();
```